# Custom Javascript Variable to return dollar amount

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

On a product page, after product options are selected a dollar amount is shown, and I am trying to create a custom javascript variable in google tag manager to return the dollar amount when the "add to cart" button is clicked.

this is the element from my page:

```
<span data-hook="formatted-primary-price">$42.00</span>
```

I'm trying to return the "$42.00" text as the "order value"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Michael. Please provide some more details so that other users can understand the problem better. For example, which JS library you are using? Or include the code you have tried in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the element using something like `priceElement = document.querySelector("span[data-hook='formatted-primary-price']")`

you could get its value using `rawValue = priceElement.innertext`.

You should also trim the dollar sign off the amount, and convert it into an integer number of cents so that you can't get stuck with floating point errors. Something like `orderValue = parseInt(rawValue.replace(/$\./, ""))`. This way your final order value for your example would be 4200.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think I was as clear in my initial question. I'm looking to create a Custom Javascript Variable in GTM. This gets me close, the event is sent successfully, but the Value is "missing. function () {
return document.querySelector("span[data-hook=‘formatted-primary-price']");
}       I tired: function () {
return document.querySelector("formatted-primary-price");
}      and it went through successfully, but this time the value provided by the tag is 0.0. the value should be 42.00

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with gtm's apis.